# If $A$ is a $2\times1$ matrix and $B$ is a $1\times {2}$, prove $C = AB$ is not invertible

Tags: matrices, proof-writing

What I tried to do was I made $2$ matrices $A$ and $B$ and set them not equal to the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix, I don't know what to do next and I am stuck on the proof so I need help on what I could do next.

Answer (score 2):

We have$$C=AB=\left(\begin{array}{c}
A_{1}\\
A_{2}
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
B_{1} & B_{2}\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
A_{1}B_{1} & A_{1}B_{2}\\
A_{2}B_{1} & A_{2}B_{2}
\end{array}\right)$$so $\det C=A_{1}B_{1}A_{2}B_{2}-A_{1}B_{2}A_{2}B_{1}=0$. Hence C is not invertible.

Answer (score 1):

For arbirtrary $v$, $Cv$ is a multiple of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

For $B$ there exists a non-zero vector $v$ such that $Bv=0$. If $B=(x,y)$ with $x\neq 0$ or $y\neq 0$ you can choose $v=\begin{pmatrix}y\\-x\end{pmatrix}$. If $B=0$ then any non-zero $v$ works.

Now $ABv=0$, so $AB$ can't be invertible.

Comment: Is there any way to prove it without vectors since I haven't learned about them yet

Comment: A vector is just a $2\times 1$ matrix.